# Control the order triggered click UI events in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a `<input type="checkbox" />` which has a click handler bound to it via jQuery's `.click` function. It then performs some calculations depending on its state:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        console.log("ACTIVE");
    } else {
        console.log("INACTIVE");
    }
});
```

That's all good in the UI, however, in my unit tests, I want to simulate a click on this element and make sure the correct code is run.

```
$(testElement).click();
```

The problem is that the handler is called **before** the default browser action, and so the values of `this.checked` are reversed. That is, it doesn't get its `checked` attribute changed until after my handler runs.

Is there any way around this? Is there a different event I could bind to? Is there a different way to trigger the clicks programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at this [blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1525-jQuery-s-Event-Triggering-Order-Of-Default-Behavior-And-triggerHandler-.htm) you might be able to get the behavior your are looking at by doing the following:

```
$( ":checkbox" )[ 0 ].checked = !$( ":checkbox" )[ 0 ].checked;
$(":checkbox" ).triggerHandler( "click" );
```

And with the use of [`triggerHandler()`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/), you will only trigger events bound by jQuery and not the default behavior.

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/8Cx3c/).**

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(":checkbox").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        console.log("ACTIVE");
    } else {
        console.log("INACTIVE");
    }
});

$(":checkbox").attr("checked", true).change();
```

Comment: this doesn't actually change the state of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Why burden your unit tests with testing jQuery? Use code directly in anonymous functions for mundane stuff and for the more important stuff use a separate function that can be unit tested independently.

Something like this:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function () { checkboxClickHandler($(this)); });
```

And in your unit test:

```
checkboxClickHandler($(':checkbox'));
```

And your function:

```
function checkboxClickHandler(element)
{
    alert(element.is(':checked'));
}
```

Comment: True, but firstly it can be difficult to get a reference to the exact function, and secondly, it doesn't help with regression testing. I'd want to see if some other code adds another handler which affects my program.