# Jquery: change event not triggered in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I have some code updating a dropdownlist, and then I fire the "change" event manually. It works like it should in firefox, opera and so on, but not in Internet Explorer. Any idea why?

Code attached below.

```
$(".bringFraktvalgRadio").click(function() {
    var selectedValue = $(".bringFraktvalgRadio:checked").val();
    $("#<%= dropDeliveryOption.ClientID %> option[value=" + selectedValue + "]").attr("selected", true);
    $("#<%= dropDeliveryOption.ClientID %>").trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: you can select the option using `$("#<%= dropDeliveryOption.ClientID %>").val(selectedValue);`

Comment: +1 welcome to Stack Overflow, Kenneth.  Does the event fire for you if you change the item using the mouse or keyboard?  Can you post the change handling function?

Comment: How is the `change` event attached to the `select`? via jQuery or something else? Incidentally, be very careful creating selectors out of runtime values: if the `selectedValue` contains space or punctuation your selector becomes invalid and may stop working. In any case you don't need to do this because jQuery allows you to set the `val()` of a `<select>` directly.

Comment: Andy: yes, it does.

Bobince: It is a ASP dropdownlist with autopostback.

Comment: Is the html of you page valid? something Javascript does not behave as expected cause you forgot to close a div or your html is malformed in anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875236/overriding-check-box-in-javascript-with-jquery/2876016#2876016) to something similar with a checkbox. Check the answer I gave has a link and don't forget to use blur and focus.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but change event does NOT work as it should in IE (mainly IE6).

1: What you shold do is to set up listener on "click" on select and then trigger "click".

2: Better way to solve it is to add your own event on select. In jQ we do it like this:

```
$("#yourSelect").bind('myChange',function(){
 //do the chacha
})
```

And then trigger it like this:

```
$("#yourSelect").trigger("myChange");
```